# How To Display Amazon Native Async Ads In Component

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-helmet

I been trying to figure this out for 3 days, I been on google and similar stack overflow posts but, all those are outdated and when I tried to implement them it didn't work. Here is what i'm currently working with and it doesn't display on page.

Any ideas?

Amazon Code

```
 <div id="amzn-assoc-ad-d4995eab-4ce3-4691-803f-d2b5661999fd"></div><script async src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US&adInstanceId=d4995eab-4ce3-4691-803f-d2b5661999fd"></script>
```

React Component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";

//! Not Working Don't Push or Deploy

const AmazonAdd = () => {
  const [amazonId, setamazonId] = useState("");
  const [amazonSrc, setamazonSrc] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setamazonId("amzn-assoc-ad-d4995eab-4ce3-4691-803f-d2b5661999fd");
    setamazonSrc(
      "//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US&adInstanceId=d4995eab-4ce3-4691-803f-d2b5661999fd"
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="amz-ad-container">
      <Helmet>
        <script className="amazonSrc" async src={amazonSrc} />
      </Helmet>
      <div id={amazonId}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AmazonAdd;
```

Comment: can you please share what issues you are facing ? or any error stack

Comment: No errors just won't display the ad, even looked into google ads and tried that and still the same issue no ads showing on the page. create-react-app sucks for monetization